# How to set mouse left click and hold to copy in helm-mode

Tags: helm, copy-paste, mouse

I'm using helm-mode in emacs to open files. However, when I try to copy the path of a file (say `/home/user1/Documents/file1.txt`) to paste it in terminal, I get a message saying

`<down-mouse-1> is undefined`

How can I defined the left-click and hold of mouse for copy in helm-mode?

Comment: Helm doesn't (and won't) support mouse according to https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/501#issuecomment-140496283.  I think you can implement your needs as a helm action and add it to relevant helm source, then use keyboard to use it. Nowadays, it is easier to custom helm actions for many helm commands.

Comment: If thats the case can you tell me how to copy a path from helm-mode?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't insist on using mouse in Emacs, implementing your request using keyboard is straightforward.  For example, if you want to copy some filename while running the `helm-find-files` command, customize `helm-find-files-actions`:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "helm-files"
  (add-to-list 'helm-find-files-actions '("Copy filename" . kill-new) :append)
  (setq helm-source-find-files (helm-make-source "Find Files" 'helm-source-ffiles)))
```

then you can use the new action "Copy filename" from helm's action menu, that is, type <kbd>TAB</kbd> (`helm-select-action`) in a helm session.

---

If you like, you can even assign a shortcut key (e.g., <kbd>C-c m</kbd>) for it, so that you can invoke that action without switching to helm's action menu.

```lisp
(defun helm-ff-run-copy-filename ()
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-exit-and-execute-action 'kill-new)))

(with-eval-after-load "helm-files"
  (define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-c m") #'helm-ff-run-copy-filename))
```

---

For other helm commands, customize corresponding action, for example, for `helm-recentf` command, customize `helm-type-file-actions` similarly.

Comment: I'm not insistent on mouse.  I need to copy the whole path not just the filename

Comment: filename here means the full path of a file.

Comment: I get the following error when I put the first add-to-list in .emacs I get an error `Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading '/Users/user1/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: helm-find-files-actions`

Comment: You can solve it by wrapping undefined variable, e.g., `helm-find-files-actions` and `helm-find-files-map`, within `(with-eval-after-load "helm-files" ...)`.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to helm.  It will help if you can modify your answer. Once it works I will accept your answer

Comment: I've just update the answer to let you put it into your Emacs initialization file, I think it should work now, though I don't test it since I don't want the function myself.